# Есть List<string[]> с заранее неизвестными размерами. Как вывести его в datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

```
 List<string[]> table = new List<string[]>();
 string[] row = new string[...];
 .... 
 table.Add(row);
 dataGrid1.IsReadOnly = true;
 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table;
```

В итоге выводится служебная информация о списке, но не содержимое. Как это исправить?

Comment: Примечание: Создавать класс понадобится, когда уже известно количество столбцов будущей таблицы.

Comment: А что будет, если вы добавите в `List` массивы с разной длиной?

Comment: Они одной длины, но заранее неизвестной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам такой вариант, с DataTable вместо List:

```
string[] row1 = new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc" };
string[] row2 = new string[] { "xxx", "yyy", "zzz" };

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < row1.Length; i++)
    dt.Columns.Add();

dt.LoadDataRow(row1, false);
dt.LoadDataRow(row2, false);

dataGrid1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогло!